# CSS File being loaded twice

Tags: 2013, css, branding

From firebug I can see that in our SharePoint 2013, `tokyo.css` is being loaded twice. Once before my `custom.css` is loaded and once after. This is causing my customization to be overridden by default styles in `tokyo.css`

This is what I have in the master page:

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/~language/Themable/Core Styles/tokyo.css %>" runat="server" EnableCssTheming="true" />
<SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="CssRegistration2" Name="/SitePages/css/custom.css" runat="server" After="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/~language/Themable/Core Styles/tokyo.css %>" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This might not be a standard/recommended practice, but might work in your case.
Try giving the link to the css file directly using the `<link>` tag rather than the `<SharePoint:CssRegistration>` tag

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/~language/Themable/Core Styles/tokyo.css %>" runat="server" EnableCssTheming="true" />
<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="/SitePages/css/custom.css" runat="server" After="/Themable/Core Styles/tokyo.css" />
```

Comment: Tried but no change. Even tried hard coding `/Style%20Library/en-US/Themable/Core%20Styles/tokyo.css` but no effect. `tokyo.css` still loads twice, before and after `custom.css`

Comment: In your master page do you have `<SharePoint:Theme runat="server"/>`?

Comment: Just searched in master page and didn't find it.

Comment: Do you have any page layouts? Check the aspx file also to make sure its not getting loaded from there.

Comment: Firebug shows a file called `pagelayouts15.css` being loaded before any other css. There is no reference for it in the master page though.

Comment: No I am talking about the page layout file. In SharePoint each page is associated with a layout file. So you can check that file for references to that particular css file. Or you can create a new page and check if the CSS is loaded twice or not.

Comment: When I try to "fix" the culprit property in `tokyo.css` I get that warning - breaking away from site definition. How do I override this property in `tokyo.css` if I can't save the edit?!

Answer (score 0):

Abhishek is right, but I'll give you the full  example that I had to use on my site. Hopefully it helps. Keep your first line the same and make sure the second one is placed after the first line, like the following:

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/~language/Themable/Core Styles/tokyo.css %>" runat="server" EnableCssTheming="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" ms-design-css-conversion="no" type="text/css" href="/SitePages/css/custom.css" />
```